# Why can't the SO give reputation to the guys who do up-vote with good eyes?

Tags: feature-request, voting

A example how to give reputation:

> If you up-vote a question or answer which has X votes, you will earn 2 reputation when its score reaches `MAX(2*X, X+10)`.

Or a simpler version (recommend):

> If you up-vote a question or answer which scores <= 5, you will earn 2 reputation when its score reaches 15.

It will help for making valuable question and answer become more active. Especially good for un-popular ones.

I saw many good answers (but be posted very late) become inactive very quickly (even if I vote them up). This feature will help such answers.

And because of the `2*X` requirement, this feature doesn't really change anything for answers which already have high votes.

The second alternative is to not give any reputation to the voting for already-high-voted answers and just give reputation for the first 5 votes (voiding unneeded digging on fake pearls). And more it has a 10-votes window (void unneeded digging on fake pearls).

Comment: Uh... It sounds like you're trying to solve the problem of posts that get a lot of votes not getting enough votes.

Comment: @Shog9 2*X penalty, if it is not enough, you can add more

Comment: I disagree: it might work right now, if only a few people get "the right" to be awarded for finding the pearls. But as soon as *everyone* might get such award, nothing is going to stop people from upvoting random posts, and then getting awarded if others do the same. And above all: why would such award be needed?

Comment: Related, where the award is a badge rather than reputation, and is limited to downvoting: [A badge that rewards “prophetic” downvoting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134551/a-badge-that-rewards-prophetic-downvoting).

Comment: @Arjan: I believe this alternate will resolve your concern: `If you up-vote a question or answer which scores <= 5, you will earn 2 reputation when its score reaches to 30.` 25-distance is huge for fake-pearls, so any one will find the **real** pearl only

Comment: @LaiJiangshan Why do you call it a "penalty"?  By that reasoning, we're all being penalized every time we vote!

Comment: @Danielδ if the X is high, it will be very hard to reach to 2*X votes. So if you try to gain such reputation for already-high-votes answers but you don't really like, you will earn nothing but waste your time and waste 1 vote cast. So it is penalty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Good content already gets upvoted. We don't need to incentivise voting up good content.
- Reputation is *supposed* to reflect just that, your reputation within the community. Why would I trust you more because you upvote a lot?
- This is extremely meta. Reputation is supposed to come from *content*, votes are not content and should not yield reputation. You're effectively trying to let people upvote your upvotes.