# Why doesn't the number of downvotes listed in my profile match the number in the detailed list?

Tags: support, profile-page, down-votes, votes-tab

Over on mathoverflow, my profile says I've made 13 downvotes.  But when I click on "view more" under "Votes Cast", there are only 5 downvotes.  What would cause such a discrepancy?

I apologize if this is well-understood -- I couldn't find it in the FAQ or by searching meta.

Comment: I suppose the 'downvotes' in the summary are all downvotes you have casted, while the 'downvotes' under 'view more' are the downvotes that are still visible (e.g. on non-deleted questions). I am not 100% sure about that though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reasoning for why it is so is explained in details [in this answer at Programmers meta](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5445/31260):

> Such votes do show up in your totals, [and also count toward various badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117846/votes-cast-should-include-votes-on-deleted-contributions/123048#123048); they have the additional advantage of *not* counting toward the daily voting limit.
>
> They *don't* show up on your profile's votes tab, because that would mean showing you links to deleted posts - that would equate to giving you broken links on your profile which would be *bad*...

13 downvotes in profile vs 5 in "view more" under "Votes Cast" mean that 8 of the posts you voted down are now deleted. There is even a proposal: [A badge that rewards "prophetic" downvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134551/a-badge-that-rewards-prophetic-downvoting)

Answer (score 4):

Votes on posts that have since been deleted are not removed from your vote counts, and [are taken into account for the various vote-related badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117846/votes-cast-should-include-votes-on-deleted-contributions/123048#123048). But you won't find them in the list of votes you've cast.