# Deleted downvotes should appear in Achievements dialog

Tags: feature-request, notifications, top-bar, achievements-dialog

"Good morning.  Here is something awesome that you got last night!", said the Top Bar:

[image: Blackjack!]

"21?  That must be two answer upvotes and, um, an answer that I downvoted that was deleted?", I thought.  Ok, let's look at the details and find out:

[image: 20 + 10 = 21?]

The +20 on my `egrep` answer is new and I've seen the other Achievements on the list, so where did the extra +1 come from?  In order to avoid confusion, the recent reputation changes in the dropdown should add up to the number in the notification.

---

I suspect this *particular case* is a bug.  Assuming the +1 is a downvote reversed by an answer deletion, I could see the argument for excluding it from the Achievements dropdown.  After all, it's not exactly something you accomplished.  Except it kinda is.  Part of the reason for downvoting is to [democratically censor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_censor) low-quality content.  The ultimate sign that such content was deemed beneath community standards is when it gets deleted.  I'm not sure that we should [award a badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134551/1438), but putting a note in your achievements in such cases seems like it would reinforce positive (albeit negative) behaviour.

This question is a feature request that **rep gains from deleted downvotes be listed in the Achievements dialog**, without getting into broader issues of displaying other activity on deleted posts such as those discussed in [Reputation items in the achievements dropdown don't add up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210139/new-top-bar-cant-math).  Thus, this is not intended to completely address the issue of the Achievements sum not adding up, but is intended to help encourage good community moderation by appropriate downvoting of low-quality content.

Comment: '... would reinforce positive (albeit negative) behavior.'? How do you mean?

Comment: @MichaelT: It's an overly clever way to say that downvoting is something we actually encourage.

Comment: Just making sure.  There are multiple parsings of that that my business rule addled brain was trying to come to terms with that seemed ambiguous.

Comment: This is a dupe of an answer in the feature announcement post.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207506/140890 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208058/140890

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Good eye.  I found one of those, but it wasn't entirely clear it was the same problem.

Comment: This morning, this question got upvoted again and again, I scored a blackjack.

Comment: Nick gave the answer in a newer question asked today - looks like the same case.

Comment: After an edit emphasizing the focus that distinguishes this from "New top bar can't math," it should be reopened.

Comment: "this friggin' light turns on every time next piece of garbage is removed from the site (happens quite frequently) ...turn these "obtrusive green fireworks" off. Changes these celebrate simply aren't worth breaking my attention" ([Is there a way to turn off this disturbing green light from the status bar?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210118/is-there-a-way-to-turn-off-this-disturbing-green-light-from-the-status-bar/210122#comment673824_210122))

Comment: It's also inconsistent, as those -1s from downvotes *do* show up.  I therefore expect to see the +1s, and when this happens I end up digging around the several sites on which I'm active to find out where it happened.  Annoying!

Comment: @MonicaCellio How can this digging even be done? Go to the profile and look at the downvotes history?

Comment: @Fiksdal look for the event in your reputation history (on your profile).  Since you don't know when you cast the vote, looking around in your voting history would be pretty frustrating.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Unfortunately, these don't always show up in the reputation history,  either.

Answer (score 7):

When you downvote an answer, the event shows up in this dialogue (but doesn't light it up).  When you post a bounty, [same thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245382/162102).  And when you lose rep because a user was removed, [that shows up here too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rcc0H.jpg).  For consistency, the +1s from these deletions should, too.  "Correcting" the notice to say +20 instead of +21 would be moving in the wrong direction, concealing the event entirely until you happen to notice it via other means.

Because most of the time you won't be able to see the deleted post, and for consistency with "user was removed" events, it would be sufficient to say "+1 downvoted post removed".  It's not necessary to identify the specific post here, just the site.  Somebody who really wants to know can go digging on his own.