# Reputation items in the achievements dropdown don't add up

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, top-bar, achievements-dialog

In the top bar, the green “achievements” number shows +14. But when I open the dropdown, I see four items totalling +20. Why does the total not match the sum of the items?

[image]

No lower entries were highlighted.

Comment: The total has been inflation corrected.

Comment: @Bart Next question: How do you short rep?

Comment: The entire SE rep system is bad at math. I see things like that on my profile page all the time.

Comment: I once saw +280; looking at the reputation change, it should have been the half. I dunno why SE wanted to give me the double reputation. `:)`

Comment: Its their way of keeping you involved on meta. Nothing like a bug, caching, or vanishing rep to do the trick!

Comment: Funny that you get 14 upvotes yet for the calulation of 14. :-D

Comment: the `+` is at the wrong position. I should be `1+4`, then it would match your todays gained reputation. :-)

Comment: My edit would be rejected for being too minor, but I'd love to change the title since "math" isn't a verb!

Comment: @JamesWebster I believe it's there intended to be somewhat humorous.

Comment: @Cruncher.. I could agree with that. (nod) I still don't like it! :P

Comment: @JamesWebster `new top bar can't add` doesn't catch the eye as much. The word math really just shows that the calculation, however arrived at, was wrong

Comment: `top bar does new math`? (for people too young to understand the reference: [new math](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Math))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750632/why-does-adding-a-trailing-comma-after-a-string-make-it-a-tuple/3750654#3750654) was deleted (by you), resulting in a net -16.

Just like your profile, we don't show changes due to deleted posts in the achievements dropdown.  They are however available in your profile if you opt to see them via the checkbox at the bottom of the reputation tab.

Comment: Then it still can't math? It should be 4 then? not 14

Comment: @Cruncher another +10 came in when he clicked the inbox that isn't yet rendered, simple timing issue there.

Comment: The rationale for not showing deleted post was not to draw attention on them. If you follow that rationale, you shouldn't display the reputation reduction either: the wrong math a flagrant invitation to go digging and trigger meta drama. If you don't follow that rationale, then display the deletion event.

Comment: @Gilles the reputation totals for today on the previous hover and on your profile tab have the same behavior, and have for years.  We have no intention of changing it.

Comment: Why not show which posts were deleted?  Maybe at least a checkbox at the bottom of the menu, to show which posts got deleted?

Comment: This is wrong. [Period](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258608/140719).

Comment: *"They are however available in your profile if you opt to see them via the checkbox at the bottom of the reputation tab."*  This must be done manually for each of a potentially large number of accounts individually; if you want to see that information and make the sum make sense it is rather difficult to do (and I'm not even sure it'd be evident then, without scrolling through the past activities for each site).