# New top-bar really doesn't know maths

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, top-bar

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210139/new-top-bar-cant-math) has been tagged [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) but I really think its a bug. I just experienced this. TWICE

First time :

[image]

Second time :

[image]

And now again

[image]

SERIOUSLY, THIS NEED TO BE FIXED... :(

[image]

IS THIS BUG AFTER ME?

[image]

Can this bug be fixed???. Pls stop giving me false hope. I really thought I had +118 somewhere :)

What is going on?

Comment: I've noticed that when something I downvoted gets deleted, and it thus puts me up one rep, the new top bar seems to completely screw up on calculating the actual gain. Had you downvoted something else in that time that has since gone *poof*?

Comment: @BillyMailman I downvoted things that got deleted but not at the time of the notification

Comment: Being from the other side of the pond, I snicker every time I see the word "maths."

Comment: My experience is the notification is your net rep gain since you last checked, not your net for the day, so if you checked it and cleared it several times, it would only show your changes since you last clicked on the menu

Comment: @psubsee2003 I don't think that is my case. I check every time I get a notification

Comment: @Tijesunimi on the same site though?  Just thinking out loud.  I haven't been answering or asking much in the last week, so I haven't had enough rep changes to see it in action on multiple sites, but once you click on it, it should go away.  However, it may not go away on all sites?

Comment: Not sure how related this is, but it's really annoying when someone deletes an answer you've downvoted and you get a +1 notification, but clicking on it won't show the deleted answer on the list. You have to dig through profile page rep change lists to find where and what answer was deleted.

Comment: @Juhana Thats the most annoying part

Comment: +1 for multiple screenshots.

Comment: You may be interested in my [Don't light up the achievements indicator when the only change is removed downvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210882), @Juhana, which Shog has in effect marked "won't fix".