# Don't light up the achievements indicator when the only change is removed downvotes

Tags: feature-request, notifications, top-bar, achievements-dialog

Fine, the [new neon sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210637/on-rep-changes-highlight-icon-in-top-bar-instead-of-showing-number)'s math [works the same as the math](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210139/new-top-bar-cant-math#comment674124_210205) did in the old pop-up. That makes sense. But this is just silly. *Why* do I need to be **notified** that a post I downvoted got deleted?

[image]

<sub><sup>(The title links next to the red -1s were removed from the screenshot by me. They're present in the real pop-up.)</sup></sub>

So I can break out a bottle of the '82 Rothschild? It's especially pointless because there's [no link to the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210205/) that caused the change.

Please don't display the Rep Signal when the change is only due to someone else's deleted posts.

Comment: "It's especially pointless because there's no link to the post." That's weird... with your amount of rep on MSO, shouldn't you be able to see links to those posts?

Comment: The removed post is on SO main, @Bolt, but the popup [doesn't display them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210205/159251) regardless of site or privileges.

Comment: Oh, you're talking about the fact that there's no titles next to the red -1s there, @Bolt. I anonymized those to protect innocent Joshes. Sorry for that confusion.

Comment: For people who don't agree: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210881/achievements-toolbar-said-i-have-a-2-but-doesnt-say-where

Comment: Related (request for consistency in the interface -- if you do light up tell me why): http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225463/162102

Answer (score 5):

Every time a downvoted post gets deleted, a unicorn gets its wings.

And you know what that means.

Yup.

Time to whip up a batch of tasty unicorn buffalo wings.

Comment: What pairs well with unicorn buffalo wings? It certainly isn't an '82 Rothschild.

Comment: Michelob with an ambrosia chaser, @Gen.