# Achievements dialogue sum error?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, achievements-dialog

Here is what my Achievements dialogue looked like earlier today.
[image]

These three items were highlighted in blue: a +10 (one upvote on an answer), a +15 (three upvotes on a question), and a -1 (a downvote I cast).  The sum of these should be +24 (or possibly +19 or +14 if I had "seen" one or two of the question upvotes already).  How could these three sum to +1?

The browser window for this screenshot is >1200 pixels wide, so I don't think it's a compression issue where things are getting cut off, and it's an up-to-date latest release (44.0.2) of Firefox.

This seems like one of those things that will either be obvious to someone other than me right now, OR a real bug.

Comment: It's a bug-by-design: [New top bar can't math](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210139) You may also enjoy [Top bar reputation accounting should add up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208251) and [New top bar really doesn't know maths](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210294)