# Achievements toolbar said I have a +2, but doesn't say where

Tags: bug, toolbar

I've just seen a green `+2` on the achievements menu button, on the newly introduced toolbar that's just a couple of days or weeks old, but when clicking on it, it didn't say which site this `+2` was at.

Any idea how to find out?  Sounds like a bug.

Comment: This is probably [New top bar can't math](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210139), in which case you might be interested in my [Don't light up the achievements indicator when the only change is removed downvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210882), posted just after this.

Comment: But what if I want to know about the removed downvotes?

Comment: Then don't vote for my feature request! :)

Comment: Related (request for consistency in the interface): http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225463/162102