# Topbar tells me about a +1 recovered from a deleted DVed post, but detail view doesn't show it

Tags: discussion, reputation, notifications, top-bar

The topbar only tells us about reputation gains (see [related issue with lost rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208900/162102)).  But sometimes it only half-tells us:

[image: screen shot]

The explanation of that +1 is nowhere to be found here.  An answer that I downvoted was deleted (hence the return of my 1 rep), but I'm active on several sites and sometimes it takes days (or weeks or months) for such posts to be deleted, so asking myself "what have I downvoted recently?" doesn't necessarily help.

If we're going to show the notification, shouldn't we also show the explanation?

Comment: Alternatively, [don't light up the achievements indicator when the only change is removed downvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210882)

Comment: There is a checkbox at the bottom of reputation tab in profile: show removed posts.

Comment: That's the reputation page, not the pop-up, @127.0.9.6, which requires you to successfully guess which site the post was removed from.

Comment: @127.0.9.6 I know, and I set that option everywhere.  But that doesn't help me see from the notification which of half a dozen or so sites this happened on.