# Do not alert the top-bar reputation notifier if downvoted answers get deleted

Tags: feature-request, reputation, down-votes, notifications, top-bar

From time to time, the reputation notifier in the top bar notifies me of a +1 reputation change, which I am pretty sure is due to an answer having been deleted on which I had cast a downvote. However, it does not show me this, let alone which answer was deleted.

While I am happy about every drop of reputation, this positive effect gets more than compensated by the negative effect that I cannot directly figure out which of my many downvotes is responsible for this and just got alerted for pretty much nothing.

I can also imagine that this is somewhat confusing for users who are not sufficiently familiar with the system yet.

I thus propose to disable notifications of such events or at least include the information, which question the deleted answer belonged to. Note that I am fine with this reputation being calculated into the next “big” event, I just oppose the alert.

Comment: Related (sort of the inverse of this, requesting that the source of the +1 be shown): http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225463/162102.