# How can I find out what was deleted when I get one of those out-of-the-blue +1 reputation notifications?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

Every now and then I'll get one of those +1 reputation notifications a lot of us get from time to time. I'm under no confusion about what causes it: something, somewhere, that I had cast a downvote on, got deleted. (Or I removed my downvote, but let's put that aside, as that case involves no mystery at all.)

However, every time, I'm curious about *what* got deleted, and why.

On the sites for which I have the privilege for viewing deleted content and mod tools, I can check the mod tools to see if anything got deleted recently and hopefully come across whatever it was. However, is there a more direct route?

**When I get a random +1, is there some direct non-brute-force way to check what got deleted?** (At the very least, on sites where I'm 10k+?)

Comment: See also [Topbar tells me about a +1 recovered from a deleted DVed post but detail view doesn't show it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225463) and [Don't light up the achievements indicator when the only change is removed downvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210882)

Answer (score 15):

There are links to the posts in the reputation history in your profile. In your profile, click on the reputation tab:

[image]

Then in the list of reputation changes under this tab, the +1 entries are included, with a link to the removed post:
[image]

Clicking on the link will open the deleted post, at least if you have the 10K permissions to see deleted posts.

Comment: This reduces the brute forcing by _a lot,_ to just one page visit per 10k site. Thanks!

Comment: Note that for this to work you have to select the checkbox "show removed posts" at the bottom of that page.