# Notification when a downvote cost is refunded

Tags: support, bug, reputation, down-votes, notifications

When I downvote an answer, it costs me 1 reputation point. When that answer is deleted, the reputation cost due to downvoting is refunded. When that happens, every once in a while I get a ‘+1’ badge appear on top of the ‘Achievements’ icon:

[image: +1]

However, when I click the icon, I don’t see anything telling me how I earned that point back: no specific notification item appears in the Achievements menu. I have to scour through the ‘reputation’ tab on each site I am registered on to even take a guess, since there usually isn’t a reputation change item in there either (I can usually see one on Retrocomputing, but not on Stack Overflow; I don’t know what it depends on). I have to infer that from what I remember having downvoted before. Which often doesn’t work either; if I cast the downvote long enough ago, I may have already forgotten it. Since I am left no wiser than before, the whole notification seems like pointless distraction.

Can something be done about this? Either:

- Tell me which answer was deleted, or at least on which site it was, or
- Suppress the notification altogether.

Comment: You can see that on your profile > activity > reputation

Comment: @Luuklag they have 45 sites, they would have to  visit all of them to find that +1

Comment: Do like me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Thgz.png and you'll never notice a +1 again ...

Comment: If you click on the achievement, what is shown in the drop down?

Comment: @rene `javascript:(n => { n.textContent = '+\u221e'; n.classList.remove('d-none') })(document.querySelector('.js-achievements-button > span.js-unread-count'))` Oh, that was easy.

Comment: When the reputation dropdown opens, even when there is not a text notification (so rather an emptiness is there), there is still a row of icons of the stacks with the most recent changes (near the top, right at the border of that empty area). I haven't yet pondered much about the ordering, but looks like in that row of icons, the one with the most recent change could be the first, leftmost one?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253247 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225463 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210882