# Discrepancy between the green rep number and the numbers inside

Tags: support, achievements-dialog

[image]

Is there a reason for this? Or is it an actual bug? I haven't received any downvotes recently, so that's not the issue.

Edit to include some questions from the comments below:

Re duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210139): I haven't deleted any posts recently, nor have any posts of mine been deleted, as far as I can tell.

[image]

IIRC, I *have* downvoted an answer (or question) before (at some point in time), but I'm pretty sure it's been at least 6 months :D.  @Shadow Wizard said that maybe the answer I downvoted (-1) got deleted (+1), and then undeleted (-1).  That's possible, I guess (I had thought that they expire after a while and only mods can undelete, but I guess that's not the case).

---

Aannd it just happened again.  (Although as @Cai pointed out, I might have already gotten the +5 from this post so this might be a false positive (aha- see what I did there))

[image]

Comment: @Sha I haven't deleted any posts recently either.

Comment: @Cullub you didn't have to delete the post yourself. Check your profile reputation tab and enable "show removed posts" (you may need to check a bunch of profiles though...)

Comment: @Cai Show removed posts is already checked, and there isn't any negative rep since January

Comment: @Cullub did you downvote any answer at any point of time? (anywhere in the network.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - that would show in the screenshot.

Comment: No, and I usually get my downvotes shown in the pop down anyway. @sha

Comment: @Mithrandir actually the downvote of the answer might occur even year ago, edited the comment.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - huh? You can see that it's been clicked since then, so the -1 would show up there.

Comment: @Cullub I see you have four downvotes [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3437608/cullub?tab=topactivity) for example. Sure they were all on questions? My point is, that answer you downvoted might have been deleted in the past (+1) then undeleted today, and the rep would drop by 1 again. (and it won't show anywhere.)

Comment: @Mithrandir I know, see above comment.

Comment: Did you maybe unaccept an answer?

Comment: @Sha wow that's deep. Well I guess it could be. How long until deleted posts expire? (and can't be undeleted)

Comment: @fedorqui that would cause -2, and should be visible in reputation history.

Comment: @Cullub they never expire. Any post can be deleted or undeleted at any time.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I was thinking on unaccepting in the site he joined that day, but I see it is not the case. What about a suggested edit that got approved in the past but the post got deleted just now?

Comment: @fedorqui -2 as well. The diff is only -1.

Comment: @ShadowWizard uhms, this is picky... I can just think about Documentation, where +1 can be earned for votes on examples where you contributed with a minor edit. Since the OP has [some history in Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3437608/cullub?tab=documentation), maybe an example was removed or a vote undone.

Comment: @fedorqui oh, that might be the case, yep.

Comment: @ShadowWizard in fact it must be some deleted example, since [his two proposed changes](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3437608/cullub?tab=documentation&sort=proposedchanges) are very minor and don't grant him +1 when upvoted (I just tested it).

Comment: You posted your SO reputation tab, but have you checked all your other accounts?

Comment: @fedorqui I think you're looking at the wrong link.. Maybe [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3437608/cullub?tab=documentation&sort=contributions&showDeleted=true)?

Comment: @Cullub oh, you are right (even though I don't know what is the difference between _proposed changes_ and _contributions_, probably the former being a subset of the latter). Do you have any deleted entry in that list?

Comment: @fedorqui no idea myself either - I didn't know you could get rep from docs.  But no, I don't have any deleted posts there.  See this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5oJS.png). And none of the posts on the linked page have any downvotes.

Comment: @Cai just checked the rest of my active accounts, but I don't think I've downvoted on any site except SO.

Comment: @all I edited my post to include some of this.  And it happened again.

Comment: hmm, you didn't already get the previous +5 from this post?

Comment: @Cai I don't know, actually. Maybe I did.  I've been on mobile most of today, and I don't know how that works exactly.

Comment: Cullub: you can read about reputation in Documentation in the Meta SO post [Documentation Reputation Update Is Live](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334551/1983854). You have a timeline of posts, where you can see how your edits are considered. [For this case](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/topic/1160), yours shows up as minor contribution: _Cullub since Oct 18 '16 at 16:09 (1 changes)_. However, yours was a modification in the Syntax section, which cannot be upvoted.

Comment: Well, if you'd already seen the previous +5 then that one looks correct (rep gains on the same post are collapsed in the dropdown)

Comment: Regarding your recent update about this happening again, note another contributor of that Documentation topic also got this +1/-1 just 30 mins ago: http://stackoverflow.com/users/5347689/niek-brouwer?tab=reputation

Comment: Related: [Topbar tells me about a +1 recovered from a deleted dved post but detail view doesn't show it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225463)

Answer (score 1):

I see this routinely - a discrepancy of 1 - and I think it's because something I downvoted was deleted. This gives me my -1 back. The thing to click on might say +11, but when I click, I only see a +10 event. There's no "event" in the dropdown for the +1 of getting my -1 back. I have also seen the loss of a +2 for editing something, and I supposed if I both suggest-edited a question and downvoted an answer to it, and the whole thing was then deleted, I would have a net of -1.

The point is, when you lose or gain rep due to the deletion of a question or answer, you don't see it listed in the dropdown of things that affected your rep. I am not sure whether you see it on your rep page or not, but my hunch is you do not, that the original entry days ago giving you the rep just goes away.

Comment: Although this is possible (+1), I don't think it is what happened this time. See the comments on the question.

Comment: Your profile rep list does show removed posts that changed your rep up or down (and with 10k on a site, also links to them).