# Got one reputation point on StackOverflow without any explanation

Tags: support

Today when I logged into my Stack Overflow account it showed me that I had got one reputation point. But when I clicked on the "Recent achievements" button on top bar there was no explanation for it. This is how it looked like to me:

[image]

Any one knows why was I awarded one reputation point?

Comment: This happened to me too recently, I think it was because a post I downvoted was deleted.

Comment: Closely related: [Don't light up the achievements indicator when the only change is removed downvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210882)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An answer was deleted and you got a point back because you had downvoted it at some point in the past.

You can verify this by looking at your [reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1047998/naveen?tab=reputation) with the "show removed posts" checkbox checked.

[The top bar doesn't show detailed reputation events related to deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210205/155160).