# Should unclear questions be flagged or downvoted?

Tags: discussion, flags, down-votes

When I mouse over the downvote button of a question, I see this:

> This question does not show any research effort; **it is unclear** or not useful.

However, there is also a flag for unclear questions (at least in SO) with the following description:

> **unclear what you're asking** 
>  Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

My question is:

What's the difference and, thus, which option to choose?

Comment: Both. Both. Both is good.

Comment: I believe the technical term is *downclosing*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually a question gets closed when it is unclear. That will [prevent others to answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98026) and let the author to clarify his post. This doesn't affect the reputation of the author.

The down-vote is a way to 'reward' the bad question (just like we reward good questions with up-votes) and it resembles the general opinion about that post. In the bigger picture this is the same for the usefulness of the contributions of the author to the community.

If you feel like it, you can both down-vote and flag / vote to close, which is the same I do most the time dealing with such posts.

Comment: _... In the name of the down-vote, the flag, and the vote to close._

Comment: @TimPost [Pale Horse Rider](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135010/165773) prayer?

Comment: @gnat +1 for giving me a motive to read the New Testament from a question regarding the flagging on SO :)