# Should there be a "Censor" badge?

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

I notice that there's a lot of moderators who are pretty comfortable with deleting other user's content.  And there are other users who have piped up about it.

Community internet sites with a voting system should not have moderators, and in ***no*** case should they **censor** posts -- except for vandalism/spam.  Disgruntled users who do not like a post *have the power to ask for clarification if there's disagreement*.  That is the adult way, not deletion, which has been both petty and academically irresponsible on Stack Exchange.

The other answers are insufficient because they answer the question from the point of view that fault from the user has already occurred or from a pseudo-guilty party, answered on behalf of disgruntled users.  I will review, however.

<sarcasm>Perhaps there should be a "Censor" badge after the user has deleted a sufficient number of posts (1 maybe)?</sarcasm>

Comment: What positive behaviour would that badge encourage?

Comment: Are you saying that the other badges are for encouraging positiive bahavior or that deleting posts is not positive behavior?

Comment: So, you want to give a mod a badge just for doing their job? Not sure how this benefits the site or why we should have moderator only badges.

Comment: @Marxos Yes, badges are meant to encourage positive behaviours.

Comment: ... @yannis deleting bad posts (not an answer answers, for example) **is** a good behavior.

Comment: @Catija Certainly. I wouldn't call that "censoring" though.

Comment: @Catija:  Do you mean posts you don't agree with?

Comment: @yannis Of course not... but as the person who posted it and who likely disagrees with the deletion, you would consider yourself censored... lots of people complain about mods overreaching because of deleted posts...

Comment: It sounds like you're angry that mods (or high rep users) have deleted something. The phrase "pretty comfortable" implies you think they shouldn't be. The role of mods and high rep users is to remove material that doesn't belong, and those who aren't comfortable with it shouldn't be in the role. I think rather than suggesting a sarcastic badge, you should ask why certain material was deleted, so you can understand the site better. Such a question probably belongs on the meta of the site where the deletions happened, not here.

Comment: No mod should ever delete a post just because they disagree with it. If that's the case, you should be addressing **that**, not posting a veiled rant about mods deleting your posts.

Comment: @Catija Trust me, I'm very much aware that lots of people complain about mods overreaching because of deleted posts. ;)

Comment: I'm guessing this is related to something that happened on [Philosophy](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/3369)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A badge that rewards "prophetic" downvoting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134551/a-badge-that-rewards-prophetic-downvoting)

Comment: @Marxos Passive-aggressive suggestion of badges in response to conflict is not a good strategy. If you believe something was wrongly deleted (sure, it happens sometimes), open a direct and polite discussion on the appropriate meta, or bring it up reasonably in chat, and be prepared to handle the possibility of a non-ideal outcome gracefully. One good approach is to ask why it was deleted first, *before* getting into reasons why you believe it should not have been. This will not only help you here, but in dealing with conflict in general.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) -- Also contains some advice for getting a post undelete. Additionally search MSE for "why was my post deleted" and sort by votes, there's some great examples of good approaches there.

Comment: You people are avoiding the issue.  I have to assume that you are sophmores.  You're skirting the issue of censorship.  If your voting model is doing it's job, *you shouldn't need moderation*.  Consider:  a *rasonable* (non-vandalized) post can have a 100000 downvotes and it would still be fallacious to consider it false *ad populum*.  Why didn't you see that before?  Oh, you were taking pot-shots *ad homineim*.  This is why I'm the Doctor.  Please talk to your advisors about our disagreements.

Comment: If you want a site without moderation, you'll have to go somewhere else. Your ideas are incompatible with the SE model. SE sites in general are heavily moderated, by design.

Comment: @gnat not dupe. This one here is for deleting, not downvoting.

Comment: No they aren't.  And if that's what SE has become, it will totally fail.  Besides you didn't notice apparently that I said moderation is tolerable in obviously vandalized submissions -- but note that this too is a danger zone and why the US allowed "everyone to be equal".

Comment: @JasonC how exactly a dupe?? OP knows how deletion works, they just suggest it will  give a badge. I'm totally against this request, but it's not duplicate of anything.

Comment: @Marxos SE's model has been highly successful to date. (It's *super* weird that you're somehow expanding this to a US thing, btw.) You're upset, and you're being passive-aggressive. Nobody is judging you for that, so just be real and own it here. Stop complaining, and don't pretend your badge suggestion was anything other than a thinly veiled rant. If you have an issue with SE's moderation model then feel free to bring it up in a post, but state it clearly instead of hiding behind a snarky badge request. If you can form your argument properly, people will engage.

Comment: Listen, all signs for sophmore-more level theory can certainly *conclude* that SE is a sucksess, but for those of us who know a little more than you do about the power of the Internet and how to recognize academic-quality answers, YOU ARE FAILING.  For example, Academia.SE is some of the lowest quality SE sites, simply because it markets itself to PhD level users, but has nearly-zero quality content.  Show me where some MIT professors are using AcademiaSE (or about any really...).  Thank you.

Comment: *"Show me where some MIT professors are using AcademiaSE"* -- http://academia.stackexchange.com/users/5912, http://academia.stackexchange.com/users/57814, http://academia.stackexchange.com/users/6309, and that's just from a 5 second cursory search of people who actually wrote it in their profiles. *"Thank you."* -- You're welcome.

Comment: @Marxos You realize that this site is for _all_ SE sites, right? If you point to one person and say, "That person is a burglar", that's not a justification for that person's entire family to be arrested. At the very most, it's a justification to investigate _that one person_, and in some cases (depending on what the initial investigation finds), the rest of the family. The same logic applies here. "This one site is doing badly" is not proof that all of SE is failing.

Comment: @Marxos Not sure what my suggestion that you own up to your passive-aggressiveness has to do with copyrighted material (?), but at this point you appear to be unable to engage in a meaningful conversation. Best of luck getting your post undeleted, and in any case SE will get along fine regardless of your personal angst. Perhaps when you cool down you can approach this again. I don't really have anything else meaningful to add here, so I'm ducking out.

Comment: Hey everyone! Obviously there's some frustration here. Maybe we can all take a break, grab a refreshing beverage, take a walk around the block, etc. @Marxos: I'm closing this question because it seems as if it's a criticism of the system rather than an actual suggestion. If you really mean it as a feature request, maybe we can edit it to explain the benefit you hope sites (and their users) will gain from the badge?

Comment: Oh, one other thing -- I was gonna fix a typo, and I noticed that you wrapped the last paragraph in `<sarcasm>`. SE strips out HTML tags by default; if you want them to show up, put backticks (`\``) around them.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes:  No, censorship, by it's nature, will make the internet fail.  Oh, perhaps, you will point out the enormous success story of the internet, too.   Please go read my analysis at hackerspaces.org/Zen_Code.

Comment: @Marxos: I'm getting a HTTP 500 trying to visit that site. I am interested in reading criticism of Stack Exchange. That said, it's hard to take a criticism seriously if it relies on sarcasm rather than a reasoned argument.

Comment: @JonEricson:  sorry, that URL is invalid.  Prepend "wiki." (w/o quotes) to the domain:  wiki.hackerspaces.org/Zen_Code.  As for the reasoned argument, it is rarely found that one who goes against the populum is seen to be "reasonable", regardless of how correct.

Comment: @JasonC:  Thanks for confirming my suspicions.  MIT profs with reputation less than 500 tells me:  either they aren't interested in the site after a quick evaluation or they've perhaps been.... censored and not able to participate?  Their profile views were less than 10, perhaps it was you.  Actually, I apologize in advance for not giving you a fair response, I'm just losing interest in teaching you, but I advise you to trust my evaluation.  There are very few around here apparently that can give you quality feedback.  If this were church, this would be called "preaching to the choir".

Comment: @Marxos uh, "preaching to the choir" would be trying to teach people who already know and agree with what you're going to teach. Do you mean something like "preaching to a stampeding buffalo" (that's a translation of a Malayalam idiom)

Comment: I am powerless against the desire to vote to delete this.  Irony is my master, and I its slave.

Comment: @Won't While tempting, the OP is a little too entertaining for me to want to delete the question, despite its uselessness.

Answer (score 14):

I'm taking this a bit seriously and ignoring the rant-ish and frustrated tone. I don't think this is a good idea, because

1. All of the acts of moderation are voluntary, but some actions require more diligence and prudence, especially those with more serious consequences. I would oppose a badge awarded for suspending people, although it's usually necessary to give perpetrators a timeout. I would oppose a badge solely for deletion for this very reason.
2. There are already mod-only badges, awarded for each year of service. Considering most work mods do involves deleting bad content, that makes this badge a bit redundant.
3. The badge name. Do we really need to discuss this?

You seem a bit heated about deletion of one/some of your posts. If so, this is not the way to make a point. You should address the deletion of the post(s) in the related per-site meta, in accordance with the "Be Nice" policy, of course.

Comment: Wow, I have to admit, even in passing, a badge for suspending people really puts all the terrible badge suggestions in perspective: that might be the single worst idea I can imagine possible on SE. Super-glad that was not serious at all.

Comment: (point 3) Apparently, YOU moderators need to discuss it.  Because that is exactly what DELETING other posts is -- unless you're trying to create a personal BLOG.  You know, a site about one's personal views.

Comment: I take issue with tje second part of your point 2.  If a moderator is spending the majority of his time deleting bad content - he isn't doing it right.  A moderator should be encouraging good content, deletion should be a small minority of his time.

Comment: @Marxos I'm not a mod, just a user that is thankful of mods because of the **voluntary** work they do for free although angry users yell at them everyday at different metas.

Comment: @Chen -- Well, it is true that the most impact an average mod is making is by deleting bad comments, NAA's etc.

Comment: @Chenmunka What do you expect a moderator to be doing to encourage good content?  All of the members of the community submit content that they (hopefully) think is useful, trusted community members are also given tools to deal with certain types of problems and other unhelpful content on their own.  When there is a problem, something that the community cannot handle on its own, or a dispute of some sort, a moderator steps in to resolve the situation.  That's their job.  It's your average non-moderator community member who's there to contribute useful content, not mods.

Answer (score 6):

Ignoring any undertone in this suggestion, I'd support if this could be handed out for non-mods as well. I'd be delighted to get a badge for deleting posts. On Ask Ubuntu, where I'm *not* a moderator, I spent a lot of time casting delete votes (something like 3700 so far), and most of these posts end up being deleted. We get badges for review queues, but there is no review queue purely for deleting. I cast most of my delete votes outside the review queues, patrolling the active questions. It would be nice to see that activity recognised some way. :)

Comment: I think the idea is that by the time you can delete things you don't really need to be encouraged with a shiny object, but then again, shiny object.

Comment: Oooooooo shiny!