# Pre-empting a close vote

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen

There are some questions that non-experts may vote to close, especially those that don't appear to be real or constructive questions, but for which an expert might know exactly what the OP is asking (the extra context coming from his/her experience in the subject) and be able to answer the (good and constructive) question.

I'm running across these questions in my own area of expertise and I can see that there are already votes in place to close the questions even though I know that the questions are good. Is there a way for me to be able to preempt or otherwise vote early to re-open?

Would editing the question be enough to remove the pending close votes?

Comment: Related: [Is miscategorization of obscure questions as “not real” a problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96310/is-miscategorization-of-obscure-questions-as-not-real-a-problem) (from none other than Eric Lippert)

Comment: Nope and nope. Improving it to stop the close votes coming in might help. And otherwise you'll have to vote to reopen once closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do anything to pre-emptively invalidate the close votes (i.e. before the question gets closed); however by editing the question you can reduce the chances of it eventually making it to 5 close votes.

You can always vote to reopen it later if it does get closed. Remember to post a comment explaining why you think it should stay open in order to make your case and to help others understand.

Comment: I'll buy most of that for a dollar.  The only thing is that it's nearly impossible to remember to go back to that question to see how its doing.  Even if I comment, there's no notification to me when the question is closed.