# close vote objection directly accessible in question

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pre-empting a close vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155682/pre-empting-a-close-vote)

Situation is this: I'm reading a question and notice someone voted to close it. I disagree but my only option is to go to the review page and work through the close vote queue and have to hope that the corresponding question comes quick (or at all). When I'm still at the site of the question, when I click on close I can only choose between the various reasons, but not "Do not close".